# Dollar symbol ($) in React/ES2015

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I notice it seems that when rendering "dynamic content" in React I have to use the dollar symbol ($) in the JSX syntax.

By "dynamic content", I refer to the fact that a React component doesn't know anything about what it needs to render until "render-time", something like passing other components as props...

```
render(){
   return(<this.props.component />)
}
```

However, I notice that when passing a variable containing the component to render I have to make use of the dollar sign...

```
...
const $content = this.props.component
return(<$content />)
...
```

This wouldn't work...

```
...
const content = this.props.component
return(<content />)
...
```

Notice I'm not using the dollar sign above

#### Question

Can anyone please explain this behavior?

I have accompanied a code snippet below that illustrates the above-mentioned behavior

```js
const ContentComponent = () => {
  return ( 
      <div className="content">
          <h3>Content</h3>
      </div>
  )
}

const data = {
    content: ContentComponent
}

const TemplateComponent = () => {

  const $content = data.content
  
  return (   
      <div className="template">
          <h3>Template</h3>
          <p>This renders the dynamic content perfectly fine using  the dollar symbol ($)</p>
          <$content />
      </div>
  )
}

const TemplateComponent2 = () => {

  const content = data.content
  
  return (   
      <div className="template">
          <h3>Template</h3>
          <p>This fails to renders the dynamic content when NOT using  the dollar symbol ($)</p>
          <content />
      </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( 
    <div>
        <TemplateComponent />
        <TemplateComponent2 />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h3 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.template {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #E57373;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #E0E0E0;
}

.content {
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #E57373;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it has to do with naming. JSX interprets components's names with the first character being a letter in lower case as html tags.

You can read more here:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

But basically,

- `<component />` compiles to `React.createElement('component')` (html tag)
- `<Component />` compiles to `React.createElement(Component)`
- `<$component />` compiles to `React.createElement($component)`

So, if you edit these 2 lines in your code snippet, it will work (I tried)

```
const content = data.content
```

to

```
const Content = data.content
```

and

```
<content />
```

to

```
<Content />
```